# Which C# multithreading option to use

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

All -

More of approach question. I have a web service whom I need to performance test from a client machine. So in essence am writing a quick WPF multi-threaded app (which has a gauge/speedometer in it) to visually indicate the request/response time. Event-driven - so when i click a button - the app will start making requests. I am only concerned about how much time it took for the request/response and not the resposne value itself (for now).

Here is my thought-process currently:

1) I need to create as many threads as I can (which my client machine can handle) and measure the performance. 2 options I can think off - creating a new Thread mechanism (so I have full control over the thread) or using a backgroundworker mechanism (so I can pass that value from background processing back to the UI). Assumption - will have to loop through the thread creation code - so can keep creating multiple threads for both approaches.

2) Dont need any progress reporting and hence that is not criteria for choosing a multi-threaded approach

3) Do need a callback method - because that should pass back the value (time taken for a request/response to the webservice)

4) When I am updating a variable with an value - will leverage any one of the synchronization methods available.

5) Havent really used the Task API from 4.0 framework - but is that something which I should consider.

Does the above line of approach look good - or am I missing something?

Really appreciate any help !!!

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes once more for tasks! Tasks are Amazing, with tasks this entire task is just a simple PLINQ loop, creating webrequests and waiting for responses.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum +1 for PLINQ. I've used it in several occasions now and it is super easy and great for this sort of thing.

Comment: fully agree with @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: You should post a little code so people know what you are trying to do a bit more. Then someone can give you some example code based on what you provide using Tasks API and PLINQ. 

This will help future people with the same problem.

Comment: Corylulu - I am currently looking for approach ideas. Absolutely agree with your suggestion. Seems like Tasks/PLINQ should be a preferred option - am just about reading it and will post a small POC in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people have recommended Tasks, which is a good idea, I think.  I don't mind using bare threads either myself, and as far as which one you should use, either will do fine.  The main thing to be wary of is the exception-handling behavior, which varies between the two.  If you have an unhandled exception in a typical thread, it will bring down your process, so you probably want to have something like this (only not oversimplified ;)):

```
int errorCount = 0;

void Run()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        try
        {
            // your code
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref errorCount);
        }
    });
}
```

On the other hand, tasks have a more controlled way of dealing with errors - they throw them wrapped in an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) when you call the Task.Wait function.

I'm thinking about exceptions for your case in particular because I assume you would end up with timeout errors during a stress test.

`Parallel.ForEach` is probably worth looking at as well, but honestly, since you're trying a stress test and not a real-world scenario, I might avoid it to be sure how many threads I'm running at once - I believe PLINQ stuff does some load balancing on the client side.

Callback methods are easy for all these methods.  I'd just use a method call, rather than passing a callback, but that's an implementation detail.

I'd stay away from the BackgroundWorker, because it's really meant for UI-related asynchronous operations, and is maybe a little bit bloated in this particular context.

Comment: Tasks are much more than just threads. Eric Lippert made that clear in his blog several times. When you fire a task it might not fire a thread (it might use an event instead for example. In the context of HTTP requests for example, an event based approach might be much better than a thread-based approach.

Comment: That's worth knowing.  Can you provide references?